# How to disable Code Migrations

Tags: entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

I've converted an AzureSQL Db to SQL Compact Db.
When I launch the ASP.Net MVC4 project I get a:

> The model backing the 'DDContext' context has changed since the
>   database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update
>   the database

I assume the _MigrationHistory table didn't get converted by the SQL Server Compact Toolbox correctly.

I don't need or want the code migration features anymore, they where only used briefly at the project beginning.

How can I get the framework to ignore what is in the _MigrationHIstory table, and give the Db the old college try?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just delete the Migrations folder from the project along with the Configuration class and any migration classes that are in there. As far as I can tell, that's all that there is to say that it's using Code-First Migrations.

Hope that helps. :)